# How to prove that $n^{n-2} = O(2^{n^2})$

Tags: computational-complexity

I'm struggling to show that : $n^{n-2} = O(2^{n^2})$
.

I know the definition of big O but I don't know any method to show this. Could you please help me giving a few methods?

Comment: $n^{n-2} = o(n^n)$, and $n^n \leq (2^n)^n=2^{n^2}$.

Comment: The takeaway from this is that exponents matter much more than bases.  The same approach shows $n^n=o(2^{n^2})$.  Even though the base of $n^n$ is rising it can't compete with the larger exponent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a less obvious approach for the cases when it will not be as simple as in Shubham's answer. Note that $f(x) < g(x) \iff \ln f(x) < \ln g(x)$ and compare the logs to get
$$
\ln\left(n^{n-2}\right) = (n-2) \ln n = \Theta(n \ln n)
$$
versus
$$
\ln \left(2^{n^2}\right) = n^2 \ln 2 = \Theta\left(n^2\right)...
$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{n-2}}{2^{n^2}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n^2}\cdot\Big(\frac{n}{2^n}\Big)^n=0$$

Comment: so you proved that this is a little o, not a big o?

Comment: @MarineGalantin $o \implies O$

Comment: yes that's why I asked :) I didn't thought about doing that why